# MySql Remote Access Denied

Tags: java, mysql, remote-access

I am trying to connect to a mysql database. When I am trying to connect over mysql Workbench, I can but over java application, it says:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'1.2.3.4' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1748)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1288)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2506)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
```

The datasource definition is:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://3.3.3.3:3306"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="12345"/>
</bean>
```

and in db , user_priviliges table is:

```
'root'@'%', 'def', 'USAGE', 'NO'
```

Could please help me to solve this problem?

EDIT:

I am using jdbcTemplate and the error is on this exact line:

```
getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql.toString());
```

Comment: post your code for open connection

Comment: Sorry, I have missed it. See the edit

Comment: I need to see your code to find where is the problem

Comment: I have edited it. When I try getJdbcTemplate().getDatasource().getConnection() , I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a an account for `'root'@'localhost'` in addition to the `'root'@'%'` account that you already have (with the same password). Why? See the [mysql docs on this subject](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html). Here is the relevant part:

> Two of the accounts have a user name of monty and a password of some_pass. Both accounts are superuser accounts with full privileges to do anything. The 'monty'@'localhost' account can be used only when connecting from the local host. The 'monty'@'%' account uses the '%' wildcard for the host part, so it can be used to connect from any host.
>
> It is necessary to have both accounts for monty to be able to connect from anywhere as monty. Without the localhost account, the anonymous-user account for localhost that is created by mysql_install_db would take precedence when monty connects from the local host. As a result, monty would be treated as an anonymous user. The reason for this is that the anonymous-user account has a more specific Host column value than the 'monty'@'%' account and thus comes earlier in the user table sort order. (user table sorting is discussed in Section 6.2.4, “Access Control, Stage 1: Connection Verification”.)

Comment: My application is running in my local pc but db is remote. And there is the root@localhost user also created.  I could not see the difference between connection over mysql workbench and an application.

Comment: I think you also need to include /databasename after :3306 in your xml.

Comment: Still negative :( The thing is, I did not know that root@localhost and root@% are users. I thought that root itself is the user. So I do not know if the passwords of them are same or not. How can I know it?

Comment: Asaph thanks so much. I have solved it by: GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'  BY PASSWORD 'password'; command. by giving the same password

Comment: @Neron: Exactly! In MySQL a unique user is defined by the username *and* the host. And so `'root'@'%'` is actually a different user than `'root'@'localhost'`. FWIW: This is totally unconventional and I'm not aware of any other piece of software that does it this way. It's a very common source of confusion for people using MySQL.